# How to define a special tikz node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

I want to define a special tikz node, that I'll use that way:

```
\specialNode[name=mynode, label=mylabel, otherTikzOptions...] (node_name) at (some_coordinate);
```

And gets coverted to:

```
\node[circle, fill=red, color=black, label=mynode, label=mylabel, otherTikzOptions...] (node_name) at (some_coordinate) {};
```

(the double label is not an error, I
want this configuration to have semantic options).

I tried `pgfkeys` but I don't really know how to pass the `otherTikzOptions`
options and get the optional `at (some_coordinate)` part.

Is it even possible to realize this kind of things with LaTeX?

Comment: Why do you want an extra command `\specialNode` and a `name` key, instead of just using your second example (which is also shorter)? Also, have you tried `\tikzset{name/.style={label=#1}}`? That basically substitutes your `name` key with `label`, although I don't know why you would want that.

Comment: @Fritz the second example is actually longer, I set the form, the color, etc. As for the name key, I went this label to have a different color and a different default position.

Comment: Okay. You can make it easier for people to help you if you create a minimal working example starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`, demonstrating what you want to achieve. That way people trying to help you don't have to do that much guessing and don't need to create an example document themselves to test it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you want something like this? I'm not using the key `name` because it is already used for other purposes in TikZ. Instead, the style in the example is called `name label` because it looks like it should generate some kind of label.

[image: Labels]

Also, you don't need a separate command `\specialnode` to make some nodes look the same. Simply define a new style `special node` or similar, that includes the needed styles.

Of course, you can also add that `special node` style to the `name label` style if you want all nodes that have a `name label` to look the same. Simly define

```
\tikzset{name label/.style={
    special node, label={[fill=green]left:#1}
}}
```

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{name label/.style={
    label={[fill=green]left:#1}
}}
\tikzset{special node/.style={circle, draw, very thick}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[special node, name label=Label 2, label=Label 2, fill=red] (node name) at (0,0) {Some Node};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

If you want more flexibility, you can use `style 2 args` instead of `style`. But since pgfkeys doesn't support optional argument, you'd always have to specify both arguments like `name label={}{Text}`. Instead you can define a new style with adjustable position and the define `name label` to use that new style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    name label/.style={name label 2={pos=left}{#1}},
    name label 2/.style 2 args={
        label={[
            pos/.store in=\MyNameLabelPos, % Store position in macro
            pos=left,                      % By default, label is left
            fill=green,                    % Some default looks for label
            #1                             % Allow override of pos and looks
        ]\MyNameLabelPos:#2}               % Actual label position and text
    }
}
\tikzset{special node/.style={circle, draw, very thick}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[special node, name label=Label 2, label=Label 2, fill=red] (node name) at (0,0) {Some Node};
\node[special node, name label 2={pos=right}{Label 2}, label=Label 2, fill=red] (node name) at (0,-3) {Some Node};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I updated my question to reflect that I use other predefined options.

Comment: @Zii8roZi Just add them to the style definition in `\tikzset`. So you have `.../.style={color=mycolor, font=\myfont, label={...` or whatever.

Comment: Update the answer. It really is that simple. If you want nodes to look the same, define a style.

Comment: @Fritz this is almost perfect. Is it possible to make the position optional? Sometimes I want to put the `name label` to the right, with this solution, `name label=right:something` wont work.

Comment: The syntax isn't as nice, but this should probably do.